# Generic Entity Framework and IQueryable<T>

Tags: entity-framework

I've started thinking about the generic EF approach, and I've found that post http://blog.damianbrady.com.au/2012/03/07/a-generic-crud-repository-for-entity-framework/

The code snippet:

```
protected Dictionary<string, object> CachedObjects = new Dictionary<string, object>();

protected ObjectSet<TEntity> GetObjectSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : EntityObject
{
   var fulltypename = typeof(TEntity).AssemblyQualifiedName;
   if (fulltypename == null)
       throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Type passed to GetObjectSet!");
   if (!CachedObjects.ContainsKey(fulltypename))
   {
       var objectset = base.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
       CachedObjects.Add(fulltypename, objectset);
   }
            return CachedObjects[fulltypename] as ObjectSet<TEntity>;
}

...

public TEntity GetFirstOrDefault<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate) where TEntity : EntityObject
{
   return GetObjectSet<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

and now, if that two lines of code are equal ?

```
adapter.db.GetFirstOrDefault<MyTable>(x => x.ID == 1);
adapter.db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);
```

I'm asking, because I don't want to load all the items into the memory and then do some filtering on them. Is there any approach to make that generic operations like that as the `IQueryable<T>` ?

Comment: What is `adapter.db`? What is `adapter.db.MyTable`?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking, because I don't want to load all the items into the memory
>   and then do some filtering on them. Is there any approach to make that
>   generic operations like that as the IQueryable ?

It loads all items and make filtering in the memory because it uses `Func<TEntity, bool>` instead of `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`. Moreover it uses some useless infrastructure for chaching sets. You just need to use `objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>` to get an object set.